# how to create first IOS mobile app?

Tags: ios

I am beginner at iOS and i want to create my first iOS mobile app. What is the software requirements needed to create my first app and what are the concepts and programming language that needed?

Comment: [Apple Documentation: Your First iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH1-SW1)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need:

- **a Mac:** any Mac that can run a recent version of MacOS X (10.7 or 10.8) will be fine
- **Xcode:** this is Apple's development environment; you can download it from the Mac app store for free

Once you have that, go through Apple's introduction: [Your First iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

You don't need an iOS device to get started -- you'll be able to run your apps in the simulator that's provided with Xcode. Eventually, though, you'll also want to have:

- **an iOS device:** any device that runs iOS 6 will be fine to get you started, and if it's one of the devices that's expected to run the upcoming new version of iOS, that's better
- **a developer program subscription:** in order to run your app on your device, and to be able to eventually submit your app to the app store, you'll need to sign up for one of Apple's developer programs. The standard individual subscription costs $99.
- **a graphics program:** (optional) it's possible to build apps out of nothing but standard parts, but being able to design your own graphics will give you a lot more flexibility; anything that can edit PNG and/or JPEG files will be fine

Comment: +1 for correctly spelling Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very broad question. I'll try to summarize...

First off, you'll need a Mac and install Xcode if you want to develop a native iOS app with Objective-C or Cocoa.

Some people choose to make an HTML5/CSS3/Javascript app and build it into an iOS app, in which case your life could me made easier by using something like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com).

In either case, you'll need to join the Apple Developer Program which will run you $99/year. From there you'll need to generate a development key and eventually submit your app to Apple for review. You can find more information on that program [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).

As far as "concepts" go... again, that's a very broad question. I do not know your technical background so it's very hard to elaborate without that context. If you're not a die hard programmer and/or your app is fairly simple, you could consider the HTML5/CSS3/Javascript approach, in which case I'd recommend [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805791.do).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need an apple computer.

Once you have that you will need to download xcode which is an IDE (integrated development environment)

Then you can start coding your apps in objective-c

To put the apps onto the app store you will need to get an apple developer license which costs 99/year